# Is this Binary Search Tree (Java) deletion working correctly?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Could someone please confirm that this Binary Search Tree deletion method I created worked properly. I attached a before and after image of what I got. I am trying to delete the root (i.e. the 7). If I am wrong, could you briefly explain which one it should've been?

Cheers!

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Where did '10' go ?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I am a bit confused. is the 9 supposed to link to the 10 as well?

Comment: It should have been at the right side of '9', if your intention was creating a self-balancing binary tree.

Comment: A) this community is about specific programming questions - not a "please review my homework" service B) even if we would be helping you here - you want to put up a real [mcve] - where you give code, and expected/actual output in well formatted **text** - never as link to screenshots!

Comment: @GhostCat Apologies....it's for clarification purposes as I am self-teaching myself the concept of BST's. If you know of a better place where I could ask such a question in the future, you could just let me know. Also, I do not have enough RP to be able to actually format the text in that sense. Again, sorry for the insane question.

Comment: Wrong. *Anybody* can format **text** within the question. You aren't allowed to put in images directly. And I am telling you: ** no** images. Use text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is half correct, however you need a node "10" on the right side of the tree.

Comment: You should have writen this as a comment, which is already been written.

Comment: @Armin thanks! will make changes to fix this. Appreciated!

Comment: @Armin found the error. Works quite nice now! Thanks again!